# TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have the following data:

```
                High
 Date
 2017-07-17    150.90
 2017-07-18    150.13
 2017-07-19    151.42
 2017-07-20    151.74
 2017-07-21    150.44
 2017-07-24    152.44
```

I was trying to get the index by putting in value inside `Highs.index(values)` but am unable to get the index.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

start = dt.datetime(2017, 7, 15)
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'google', start)
highs = df['High']
print('Index = ',highs.index(150.44))
```

When i use `print('Index = ',highs.index(150.44))` i get the type error:

> print('Index = ',highs.index(150.44))
>
> TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable

Is their anyway to get the  datetime index using a particular value from the dataframe?

Comment: What is the _150.44_?

Comment: sorry, edited the question, please check now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use square braces since you are trying to index/slice into the DataFrame's index. So, instead of

```
df.index(...)
```

Use

```
df.index[...]
```

---

However, it seems you want to get the index of the column where the `High` is 150.44. You can do that like this, with *boolean indexing*:

```
highs[df['High'] == 150.44].index
# DatetimeIndex(['2017-07-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Or, more simply:

```
highs[df['High'] == 150.44].index.tolist()[0]
# Timestamp('2017-07-21 00:00:00')
```

Comment: `Highs[df['High'] == 150.44].index` This returns date but with unnecessary information, is their anyway to just get output like `2017-07-21` @Coldspeed ?